# Associating a message type with a payload type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a message bus API, where messages can only be sent with a payload of a particular type / shape.

I'm basically doing this so that when I start typing a call to `emitMessage` (below), I'd like for an IDE to be able to provide compile-time type hints for the `payload` argument once I've specified the `type` argument, so that I know what kind of `payload` is expected for any given message type.

I've tried going about this with something like the following:

```
// I create some generic payload interface that can be any shape
interface Payload<T> {
    [key: string]: any
}

// I define an enum of permitted message types
enum MessageType {
    TEST
}

// And then I expose a function for emitting messages of a particular type
// along with its associated payload
function emitMessage<Msg extends MessageType>(type: Msg, payload: Payload<Msg>) {
   // ...
}
```

But this code is incomplete / incorrect, because I have no idea how I'd specify that a specific variant of the `MessageType` enum is associated with a particular specialisation of `Payload`.

I'm unsure if this is even possible, so any help in that direction would be massively appreciated.

Comment: So you want some sort of router that depending on the message type sends the payload to some other method that can deal with it?

Comment: @solarc No, perhaps my explanation was insufficient. When I call emitMessage, I'd like for an IDE to be able to provide compile-time type hints for `payload` once I've specified the `type`, if that makes sense? So that I know what kind of payload is expected when providing a given message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really cool solution in the form of [index types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)

```
// I define an enum of permitted message types
enum MessageType {
    TEST
}

// This interface is then used as a kind of "type directory"
interface Payload {
    [MessageType.TEST]: {
        test: boolean
    }
}

// payload's type here is now an index into the Payload type directory
function emitMessage<M extends MessageType>(msg: M, payload: Payload[M]) {
    switch(msg) {
        case MessageType.TEST: {
            // payload.test is suggested by my IDE now! 
        }
    }
}
```

This feature is awesome and I'm gunna use it for everything

Answer (score 1):

One approach is using discriminated unions. First add a field to your payload which indicates its type, like `kind` beliow

```
interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}
interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}
interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}
```

First we declare the interfaces we will union. Each interface has a kind property with a different string literal type. The kind property is called the discriminant or tag. The other properties are specific to each interface. Notice that the interfaces are currently unrelated. Let’s put them into a union:

```
type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;
```

Now let’s use the discriminated union:

```
function area(s: Shape) {
  switch (s.kind) {
      case "square": return s.size * s.size;
      case "rectangle": return s.height * s.width;
      case "circle": return Math.PI * s.radius ** 2;
  }
}
```

See [Advanced Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)