# Payload type inference for events with a given type

Tags: typescript

I have a scenario where I have different events like the following:

```
type EventType = 'foo' | 'bar'

type Event = {
  type: 'foo',
  timestamp: number,
  payload: { a: number }
} | {
  type: 'bar',
  timestamp: number,
  payload: { b: string }
}
```

Then I have a listener like this:

```
on('foo', event => {
  // Here we should know that the type must be 'foo',
  // and therefore the payload has the shape {a: number}
  // but I don't know how to tell that to TS
})
```

I've tried a few different things, but so far all I've managed is for the compiler to stop compiling

I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167093/associating-a-message-type-with-a-payload-type) could help, but I didn't manage to get it working. I think the problem is that I'm using a literal union instead of an enum.

I imagine this is a situation happening in many places, so I was hoping to find a solution more easily.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq3ZZw) work for your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz yes! it gives me the type recommendations based on the first argument of the `on` function, which is exactly what I'm looking for. I'd really appreciate an explanation, but even just submitting that code I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is to make `on()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function in the type `K` of its first argument, and then write the type of the `event` callback parameter in terms of that.

To that end I would first write a helper type called `EventMap` like this:

```
type EventMap = { [E in Event as E['type']]: E };
```

which [remaps `Event`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to an object type whose keys are the intended first argument to `on()` and whose values are the type of the `event` callback parameter, like this:

```
/* type EventMap = {
  foo: {
    type: 'foo';
    timestamp: number;
    payload: {
      a: number;
    };
  };
  bar: {
    type: 'bar';
    timestamp: number;
    payload: {
      b: string;
    };
  };
} */
```

Armed with that type, `on()`'s call signature can be written as:

```
declare function on<K extends keyof EventMap>(
  type: K,
  cb: (event: EventMap[K]) => void
): void;
```

So the `event` callback parameter is of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `EventMap[K]`, which is the value type of `EventMap` at key `K`.

Let's test it out:

```
on('foo', event => {
  event.payload.a.toFixed(2); // okay
});

on('bar', event => {
  event.payload.b.toUpperCase(); // okay
});
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBpFSDeAoJTSVgWQCl4QAbAL0y1t1wBcBPGZAUQDcJgGkBeGvXrNWALiQByAGYB7GRIA0OIUgYBLAg3AxxwAK5gARhABOSlUjhNyMkABNxGJCF0HjJpAF9luT0gA+gioiEOIShiAmij7CGtBaYDp4bqbmKlY29o5IhuJQDCZqwADmXjHeMSFInNwMALIgMPyYSADabEhF1Vw8zlDVrRIhEgC6I+IdngDcMQD0AFSqLOw99Y3N2BayMo4xQiFh2xIzFoxx+dquRqYnpxm2DkGnzlfutxbTe17v9BEmu88DpI-scvmdNJdktcTD8hPcsk9TrkkPlCiVYfRPh8fn55rMYnYIPByJFkFI9MB4OoZMAkDSADzoCAADwY3Ds-QA1hAmDIpN1ag0YAA+AAUXyBKDSQngyNFEFWE1WQtaKBGAEp+MKkBwZGo7DF1eJdfqZjEaaLpHJFEgFbUtYjcHaeAA6eF2F0gF0MGQAMTUzIgdlFACZ1VMkLNZnTOSAmOV1ebgJaQQpbasHZsVM6GG645kPYZvTIAKowVgmADCICgEFF4cj0ZksfjQk8ieUFQqQA)

Comment: Excellent answer. Works great, and very clear explanation of the solution as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

```
if (event.type == 'foo') {
   // event is Extract<event, {type: 'foo'}>
   event.payload.a
} else {
   // event is Exclude<event, {type: 'foo'}>
   event.payload.b
}
```

Comment: isn't it possible for TS to know the type of `event`?  this solution makes me manually check the event type, which is not what I'm trying to do